# Looking for a short story about an asteroid impact

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story in the early 1990's, probably sometime in the 1993-1994 school year.  I think it was in a Scholastic magazine or catalog (not Storyworks.)

The story is about the discovery of an asteroid that is going to hit the Earth and cause a mass extinction.

It is told mostly from the point of view of young boy, and is his recording of how he spends his remaining time before the impact.

The end of the story is an alien who finds the boy's recording, and then one of the alien's parents says that they have something to tell him, mirroring how the boy found out about the coming impact.